# Symfony 3 form collection of entities with FOSRestBundle

Tags: php, rest, symfony, fosrestbundle

We are using the `FOSRestBundle`. Assume I would like to create a `Ticket` object via API with the following JSON body:

```
{
    "title": "I need help",
    "symptoms": [1, 4, 6]
    "author": 31
}
```

The author and array of symptoms reference primary keys in the database.

My form building looks like:

```
$builder->add('title', TextType::class);
$builder->add('author', EntityType::class, [
    'class' => User::class
]);
$builder->add('symptoms', CollectionType::class, [
    'entry_type' => EntityType::class,
    'entry_options' => [
        'class' => Symptom::class,
    ],
]);
```

The problem is that `title` and `author` are assigned correctly to the ticket object but the array of `symptoms` is not transformed into an collection of entities. Additionally there is an error that `This form should not contain extra fields`.

How should the form builder look like if I would like to assign a collection of entities to an object?

Answer (score 0):

> This form should not contain extra fields

This error means that the form structure has changed between its creation and the submission. Are you using an AJAX request to modify the DOM dynamically?
I think you should take a look [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html)

For the empty array of tags you should set the **allow_add** option to true in the definition of symptoms widget
Take a look [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#allow-add)

for more details ;-)